Looking for API services with high throughput for token price and market data
In my project, I use the DexScreener API to fetch and display token information to users, such as price, liquidity, market capitalization, and price changes over different time intervals. DexScreener is a great service, but it lacks paid options, and I'm strictly limited to 300 requests per minute, which may be insufficient as the project grows.
An important requirement: the information should be available as quickly as possible after the launch of the token's initial liquidity pools!
Please recommend alternatives to DexScreener that can also quickly and effectively provide information about the token's market conditions based on its contract address.
Alternatively, perhaps there's a way to overcome this limitation? I appreciate your responses and assistance in advance!

Clarification: I'm willing to consider paid services, as long as they solve my problem
